# Angular 2 HTML page displaying twice instead of once

Tags: html, angular, typescript, routes

I have an Angular 2 app where the default page is a toolbar. It displays properly, but for some reason it is displaying twice, i.e. two identical toolbars on top of each other.

Here is my app.html code:

```
<p-toolbar>
    <div class="ui-toolbar-group-left">
        <button pButton type="button" label="Home" routerLink="/"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-toolbar-group-right">
        <button pButton type="button" label="About" routerLink="/about"></button>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        <button pButton type="button" icon="fa-cog" routerLink="/test"></button>
    </div>
</p-toolbar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Here is my app.module.ts file:

```
import { AppComponent } from "./components/app.component";
import { AboutComponent } from "./components/about.component";
import { TunerComponent } from "./components/tuner.component";
import { CoreService } from "./services/core.service";

import { routing } from "./app.routes";

import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { SliderModule } from "primeng/primeng";
import { ButtonModule } from "primeng/primeng";
import { PanelModule } from "primeng/primeng";
import { ToolbarModule } from "primeng/primeng";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        routing,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        PanelModule, 
        ToolbarModule, 
        ButtonModule, 
        SliderModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AboutComponent,
        TunerComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        CoreService
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my app.routes.ts files:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { AppComponent } from "./components/app.component";
import { AboutComponent } from "./components/about.component";
import { TunerComponent } from "./components/tuner.component";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "about",
        component: AboutComponent
    },
    {
        path: "tuner",
        component: TunerComponent
    },
    {
        path: "",
        component: AppComponent,
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

and here is my Index.cshtml file:

```
<cache vary-by="@Context.Request.Path">
    <app>
        Loading App Content...
    </app>
</cache>

@section scripts {
    <script src="~/vendor.bundle.js"></script> <!-- Vendor Bundle Includes all outside requirments -->
    <script src="~/main.bundle.js"></script> <!-- Includes development code / Angular 2 -->
}
```

I've just updated from Angular RC4 to Angular 2.2.4. Everything seems in order, I'm unsure of why this is happening.

Comment: On what page(s) is the toolbar displaying twice?

Comment: @AngularFrance My default page is http://localhost:5000. The routing makes the app load AppComponent, so app.html is being displayed twice.

Comment: So, you're saying the toolbar is displayed twice **on all pages** (about, tuner...)?

Comment: @AngularFrance Not all pages, just the home page.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have two copies of the `<my-app>` tag in `index.html`?

Comment: I'm sure - I've appended my index.cshtml file to the post.

Comment: I don't know then, sorry

Comment: Are you hosting in IIS by anycoincedence?

Comment: @S.Robijns I am not using IIS.

Comment: Ok I was just checking because we've had a similar problem because we had a redirect to the index.html page for 404 Not Found in our web.config when hosting in IIS